# Mobile horizontal scroll bar at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, mobile, scroll

When I view my site on mobile there is a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom and you can drag the content off the screen. I tried the overflow-x hidden but it did not remove the bar.

https://www.feastfromhome.com/

Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your `<header>` element
More precisely on its pseudo ::after element...

Indeed, to center the logo, and provide a decent size, the width is set to 160%... right? That's why you have this scrollbar

Apply `overflow:hidden` to the parent, so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px)
    .bgimg-1 {
      background-position: center top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      top: 0;
      background-size: 180%;
      min-height: 51%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```